# Excel Chart Ignore/Separate (2) Max Values

Tags: excel, time, charts, dataset, max

Trying to chart a data set w/ (2) max values in the data that are always considerably higher than the rest of the data. When you chart it as normal `Chart 1` the data is skewed because of the (2) max values in the data set. Is there a way to ignore the (2) max values `Chart 2` and chart them separately as in `Chart 3`? Or put the max values on the same chart but a secondary axis? Prefer not to use helper columns because of 100k+ rows of data. Open to using vba suggestions.

```
|  Amount |     Time    |
|:-------:|:-----------:|
|    50   |  8:30:00 AM |
|   100   |  9:30:00 AM |
|    80   | 10:30:00 AM |
| 100,000 | 11:30:00 AM |
|    90   | 12:30:00 PM |
|    60   |  1:30:00 PM |
|   500   |  2:30:00 PM |
|   600   |  3:30:00 PM |
|    10   |  4:30:00 PM |
| 900,000 |  5:30:00 PM |
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So just use an if() to replace values greater than 1000 (or whatever value you consider relevant with NA() like so:

```
if(A1>1000,na(),A1)
```

Drag down in a column of your choice and use that for the chart data.

The do the reverse for the other chart version:

```
 if(A1<1000,na(),A1)
```

Comment: Yea I was hoping to do it w/out helper columns because there is like 100k rows of data.

Comment: @mjac well that would have been useful info to put in the question... But without a helper column you may well be looking at vba.

Comment: Ok I am fine w/ vba. I will look into that. I will also revise my question to make it clearer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You also have the option of selecting the individual points you want to omit on the graph, choosing format data point and selecting no fill and no border. Then you will have to adjust the y-axis scale manually to view the remaining points.

[image]

For the second graph, select the whole series and set no fill and no border. Then just set border and fill to (say) automatic for the two points you want to show:

[image]